# Large File export to postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I need to export a 50gb file with inserts to a table in postgreSQL to be able to count the time it takes to perform the inserts, but I can't find any way to load that file, can someone help me?

Comment: What does your file look like? 50 GB insert statements is not a very good idea. I would suggest to use a flat file and Postgresql COPY statement. Here is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Comment: What are you exporting out of?

Answer (score 0):

If the file have you have contains syntactically valid SQL (like `INSERT` statements), this is very straightforward using the command line `psql` client that comes with a Postgres installation:

```
psql DATABASE_NAME < FILE_NAME.sql
```

You may also want to replace `DATABASE_NAME` with a connection string like `postgres://user:pass@localhost/database_name`.

This causes your shell to read the given file and pass it off to psql's stdin, which will cause it to execute commands against the database it's connected to.